# Django two model inheritance one model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Given the following code:(don't mind the Fields there're just for illustration)

**Models**

```
class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
Fields

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
delete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
Fields

class MyModel(CommonInfo, UserModel):
my_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
Fields
```

**Serializer**

```
class MySerializer(views.APIView):

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = '__all__'
```

**Views**

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
serializer_class = MySerializer
```

**URLs**

```
router.register(r'studio', MyViewSet, basename='studio')
```

This upside model, Serializer & Views use. I use in Django REST Framework. but when I call MyModel they give me an error.

*Return the following error when API call*:

> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

**Error stack**

```
Internal Server Error: /studio/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 45, in list
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
  File "/home/chetan/Workspace/PhotoLab/PhotoLab/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 110, in get_serializer
    return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
[21/Mar/2021 13:15:33] "GET /studio/ HTTP/1.1" 500 99610
```

Comment: can you provide the error stack trace, to see what's causing it?

Comment: @RadwanAbu-Odeh update error stack please check. Thanks in advance. happy coding.

Comment: I think the problem is that you are inheriting APIview for a serializer.

Comment: @MaratMkhitaryan can you give me suggestions on what can be changed.

Comment: Your model based serializer can inherit from `serializers.ModelSerializer`. Look at [the DRF documentation for serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting from `APIView` for you `MySerializer` class.

to fix that, inherit from `ModelSerializer` from Django rest framework serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

and everything should be resolved.

Comment: Thank you @Radwan Abu-Odeh Happy Coding.